# javascript input number - detect increase and decrease

Tags: javascript

For number, I want it to perform different action if the up button is clicked, and different action if the down button is clicked. I tried to capture it with onmouseup and onmousedown. but still both are triggered. How do I know if number up was clicked and number down was clicked? I need to operate according to previous value and next value of number. so for example the value of number is 12. if the user increments it and makes it 13, I have to do a different action.

```
<input type="number" onmouseup="alert('clicked up');" onmousedown="alert('clicked down');" onkeydown="return false" min="1" max="@selvalue.Selection.MaximumChoice" id="option_@selvalue.ValueId" value="1" onchange="numberValueChange(@selvalue.ValueId, this.value,@selvalue.SelectionId);" class="form-control mb-1" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

New Added Codes:

```
function numberValueChange(optionValueId, numberValue, selectionId) {

            var number = document.getElementById('number_' + selectionId);
            var thisnumber = document.getElementById('option_' + optionValueId);


            let oldValue = parseInt(thisnumber.value);

            thisnumber.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                console.log('eski deger: ', oldValue);
                let newValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
                console.log('yeni deger: ', newValue);
                if (newValue > oldValue) {
                    console.log('bu deger arttı.');
                    var options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#multipleselection option"))
                    options.filter(option => option.value.includes(optionValueId))[0].value = (optionValueId + ',' + numberValue);
                    number.value++;

                } else if (newValue < oldValue) {
                    console.log('bu deger azaldı.');
                    thisnumber.value--;
                }

            });

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a framework? Please state which one because it's very possible the solution depends on it. With React for instance this is very easy to achieve.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/srkz4xmg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to detect *mouse clicks*, detect *changes to the value*.  Regardless of how those changes were made.

Store the value somewhere, then compare it when the input changes.  This will tell you if the new value is higher or lower.  For example:

```js
let myInput = document.querySelector('input');
let oldValue = parseInt(myInput.value || 0);

function numberValueChange(el) {

  // other code you may have, etc.
  
  console.log('old value: ', oldValue);
  let newValue = parseInt(el.value);
  console.log('new value: ', newValue);
  if (newValue > oldValue) {
    console.log('The value increased.');
  } else if (newValue < oldValue) {
    console.log('The value decreased.');
  }
  oldValue = newValue;

}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="return false" value="1" onchange="numberValueChange(this)" />
```

Comment: here is the command you wrote should be for the onchange event. because the id value you define as myinput differs. I send and capture this number id value as a parameter in the onchange event. When I try to implement this code for onchange, the old value and the new value will always be equal.

Comment: @macklee: Good catch on the event type, not sure why I used `click` instead of `change`.  I've updated the code, and you can see that the old value and new value are indeed different on each handling of the event.

Comment: I'm sure the code you wrote david works. there is absolutely no problem here. But I defined the change operation in a function. so it is not triggered on first click. triggered from the second click. this will solve my problem if the code you wrote is outside of my function. but if i export this code i don't know how to catch number id value. I added my new codes

Comment: @macklee: Well, don't assign a click handler inside of a function that is itself a click handler.  You're using inline handlers in your HTML, so I've updated the answer to more closely match that.  Either use inline handlers in the markup itself *or* bind handlers in the code (preferred), but not both.

Comment: I said that I am capturing the numberid value in the function. in your method oldValue is already taken. that is, it can be defined outside the function because it is taken over a known inputnumber. but there is a numberinput whose name has not been caught yet. and this is caught in the numberinput function. naturally, this new value is assigned as oldvalue. so always oldvalue and newvalue will be equal to each other. the issue is: how can the oldvalue be retrieved inside the function?

Comment: @macklee: In this example `oldValue` is initialized by default to `0`.  You can initialize it to anything you want.  If you have multiple inputs, you will likely require multiple "old values".  An array of objects seems reasonable, where each object contains some key to identify it and its "old value".  Overall the point is the same... Store the old value, use it for comparison when examining the new value.  *Where* you store it, *how* you store it, etc. can change based on your needs.  You just need to persist that value somewhere so it can be used for comparison with the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

`onmouseup` means the mouse button has been released, not that the mouse has clicked the up button.  Just use a `change` event then write some code to detect whether the value went up or down.

Comment: here is the problem. How do I catch the value going up or down?